# Python Mock not getting assigned for class

Tags: python, pyspark, python-unittest

I have my python class

```
class FetchData:

    def __init__(self, spark):
        self.spark = spark

    def filter_data_from_s3(self, table_name, s3_location, sql_query, table_schema, partition_column):

        # DO SOMETHING
```

Another file which calls this class is FilterData.py

```
from accessor.FetchData import FetchData
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


import sys


def main(args):
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("ROAD") \
        .config(conf=sparkConf) \
        .getOrCreate()
    try:
        args_map = DataUtils.parse_args(args)
        logger.info("Parsed Argument Map for Filtering Data : {}".format(args_map))
        f = FetchData(spark)

        for table in table_list:
            table_name = table.get("table_name")
            s3_location = table.get("s3_location")
            sql_query = DataUtils.un_parametrize(table.get("sql_query"), args_map)
            table_schema = table.get("table_schema", args)
            f.filter_data_from_s3(table_name=table_name,
                                  s3_location=s3_location,
                                  sql_query=sql_query,
                                  table_schema=table_schema,
                                  partition_column=args_map.get('partition_column'))
    finally:
        spark.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

I have written a test case to test filterData.py main function 
I want to mock filter_data_from_s3 call.

Here is the test case i have written -

```
class TestFilterData(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('accessor.FetchData')
        def test_main_call_times_for_na(self, fetch_data_mock):
    print(fetch_data_mock)
    spark_session = get_spark_session()
    CUSTOMER_ACCESS_SCHEMA = StructType(
        [StructField('enc_customer_id', StringType(), False),
         StructField('marketplace_id', IntegerType(), False)]
    )
    df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        ("customerid1", 1),
        ("customerid1", 2),
        ("customerid2", 2)
    ], CUSTOMER_ACCESS_SCHEMA)

    fetch_data_mock.filter_data_from_s3.return_value = df
    test_args = ["", "--run_date=2018-09-01", "--num_days=730",
                 "--region=NA", "--marketplace_id=1", "--region_id=1", "--num_asins=1000"]
    FilterData.main(test_args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When i call my test case, it actually makes call to filter data and fails. Rather I want my mock method to be called.
I am new to python and facing this issue for around a day now. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing `main()` from `filterData.py` then you should be mocking `FetchData` in `filterData.py`. That is, instead of `@patch('accessor.FetchData')` it should be `@patch('filterData.FetchData')`

Always mock objects where they're being used, not where they originate from.

The problem you're having is that even if you're patching the symbol `accessor.FetchData` to point to a different object (the mock), by the time that instruction is applied in your test, the module under test, `filterData` has already imported the *reference* to the original object in its namespace. It doesn't matter now that you've changed the origin module's `FetchData` symbol to something else, it won't affect the `filterData`'s namespace. If you want `filterData` to lose the original reference and point to your mock you have to point its own `FetchData` symbol to that mock.

**EDIT**

Based on the way your code is using `FetchData` this is how I would setup my mock for the kind of introspection you're looking for.

```
import mock

@mock.patch('filterData.FetchData')
def test_main_call_times_for_na(self, fetch_data_mock):
    spark_session = get_spark_session()
    CUSTOMER_ACCESS_SCHEMA = StructType(
        [StructField('enc_customer_id', StringType(), False),
         StructField('marketplace_id', IntegerType(), False)]
    )
    df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        ("customerid1", 1),
        ("customerid1", 2),
        ("customerid2", 2)
    ], CUSTOMER_ACCESS_SCHEMA)
    fake_f = mock.Mock()
    fake_f.filter_data_from_s3.return_value = df
    # ensuring that I also control the instance returned by filterData.FetchData 
    fetch_data_mock.return_value = fake_f

    test_args = ["", "--run_date=2018-09-01", "--num_days=730",
                 "--region=NA", "--marketplace_id=1", "--region_id=1", "--num_asins=1000"]
    FilterData.main(test_args)

    assert fake_f.filter_data_from_s3.call_count==11
```

Comment: I have updated the question, It was a miss paste from my side. Still facing the issue, the actual function is called.

Comment: Read my reply carefully. You should still not be patching at the origin module level. You should be patching where the object is being used.

Comment: Is there a way to get this information that how many times filter_data_from_s3 is called ?

Comment: @WhiteShadows it might be dependent of the version you're using, but I'm aware that there's a `call_count` attribute you can access on the mock.

Comment: call_count returns me 1, but ideally filter_data_from_s3 is called 11 times. I am using fetch_data_mock.call_count.